# Reusing a Neural Network

Tags: android, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm very new to Neural Network's, but for a Project of mine they seem to fit. The application should run on a Android phone in the end. My idea is to use TenserFlow, but I'm not sure if its a fit.

I have following Situation, My Input is a Set of Images (the order of them should not have any impact on the output). The Set size is not fixed, but in most cases lower then 10. My output for the whole set is just a binary categorisation (Pass/Fail).

I will have a Convoluted Neural Network, which calculates two outputs, an weight and a pass/fail value. Each Image is supplied seperately to this CNN, the resulting values are then aggregated into a final pass/fail value by using a weighted arithmetic mean.

My Question is, can I train such a network with TensorFlow?

I do not have the values for the CNN outputs in my training data, but only the outputs after the aggregation. Is this possible in general with a gradient oriented Framework or do I have to use a Genetic Algorithm aproach for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do this with tensorflow. After you've done the intro tutorials, you should look at the [CNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html) to learn how to implement a convolutional neural network in tensorflow.
All of the heavy lifting is already taken care of. All you have to do is use the tf.nn.conv2d() method to make the convolutional layer, and then use one of the pooling and normalization ops and so on.
If you're unfamiliar with what this means, you should [read up](https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/) on it, but in a nutshell, there are three unique components to a CNN. The convolutional layer scans a window through the image that looks for certain patterns and its activations are recorded in the output as a grid. It's important for learning to lower the dimensionality of the data, and that's what the pooling layer does; it takes the output of the convolutional layer and reduces its size. The normalization layer than normalizes this because having normalized data tends to improve learning.

If you only have the aggregate outputs, then you need to think of a way of coming up with reasonable proxy outputs for individual images. One thing you could do is just use the aggregate output as labels for each individual image in a set and use gradient descent to train.

Comment: comming up with reasonable proxies will not be that easy. I doubt that just using the labels will work, because some images will be highly relevant for the end result and some barely. I think I will read a bit about approaches with Genetic Algorithms for envolfing the Network which may be a better fit for my problem

Comment: I'm not sure if the choice of algorithm is the issue here. The problem is that the final output is supposed to be the average of the outputs of each image in a sample, but you only have the final outputs. Based on this, it is impossible to know which image had the most impact on the result. However, if you have many training sets, you can start to infer this based on certain types of images being more frequent in the examples that pass, and certain images being less frequent.

Comment: If you assign each image the average output of its set as label, then images that are more important will tend to have a higher label and would get picked up by the model. From a bayesian standpoint, this would be the most natural thing to do, because that is the amount of information you have in the data.